# Putting a switch inside of do...while

Tags: c++, switch-statement, nested

So I have a do... while statement that is supposed to repeat unless the user enters one of four things. Those four things have a break and they set the variable that controls the while to true, where the default is false. If the user does not enter one of the four answers, the variable will stay false, which should make the do...while start again. It doesn't.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int q5_answer = 1;
    int q5_answerU;
    int total_score;
    bool q5_valid = false;

    //Question_5:
    do
    {
        cout << "Question 5 (#1 is correct)" <<endl;
        cout << "1.) Answer 1" <<endl;
        cout << "2.) Answer 2" <<endl;
        cout << "3.) Answer 3" <<endl;
        cout << "4.) Answer 4" <<endl;
        cin >> q5_answerU;

        switch (q5_answerU)
        {
        case 1:
            cout << "Correct!" <<endl;
            q5_valid = true;
            (total_score = total_score + 1);
            break;
        case 2:
            cout << "Incorrect" <<endl;
            q5_valid = true;
            break;
        case 3:
            cout << "Incorrect" <<endl;
            q5_valid = true;
            break;
        case 4:
            cout << "Incorrect" <<endl;
            q5_valid = true;
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Invalid answer" <<endl;
        }
    } while (q5_valid = false);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The condition inside the `while` is an "accidental" assignment, not a comparison. It needs to read `while (q5_valid == false)` or more idiomatic `while (!q5_valid)`.

Comment: Or use `while(false == q5_valid)` -- this works for other tests than boolean too (`42!=answer`) and the compiler will automatically catch an accidental assignment

Comment: @sehe: Better turn on compiler warnings and watch them, please. ;)

Comment: @sehe: I just sends shivers down my spine when someone proposes the yoda conditionals. :(

Comment: @Xeo: well consider the practical side: if you do a lot of template program you get to value prevention of any compiler warnings (especially with -Werror); The 'Yoda' (+1!!!) conditional has one benfefit mostly overlooked: it prevents me from ever commiting the mistake. It reminds me to think about rvalue/(const) lvalue-ness in all contexts. This is just a Good Habit(TM). If the 'Yoda' style confuses anyone on first reading, +1 for it, since there is nothing spiffy going on; shivers are purely psychological (_I'm not gonna drag badly designed classes with evilly defined operators in this mix_)

Comment: I did use the Yoda conditional (great name, by the way) for quite a while for the above reasons but it now seems that most compilers tend to throw a warning about the accidental assign these days and the group of developers I work with prefers their conditionals the right way around. That said, I'm really not a big fan of explicit comparisons of booleans as I find them harder to read than the the "non-comparison" kind like ´if (condition)` or `if (!condition`).

Answer (score 4):

This is not a boolean expression:

```
q5_valid = false
```

It sets the variable q5_valid to `false` and also returns `false`. Replace it by:

```
!q5_valid
```

or

```
q5_valid == false
```

Which are the same. The former is better for readability.